# Alphabetical sorting of refnames in Git, how does it work?

Tags: git

How does Git sort refnames and where do I read up on that?

Why I'm asking: I want to archive my branch under "archive/", but I would rarely need them, thus I don't want to see them first in my list of branches. I couldn't come up with a meaningful name further back in the alphabetical order, so I thought about starting it with "_archive". Then I tried to find how sorting is done in Git, but failed, thus this question.

Comment: Wouldn't `git branch | grep -v archive/` be a better solution, preferably in an alias? Try `git config --global alias.br '!git branch | grep -v archive/'` then just `git br`

Comment: Name your branch zzzzzzzz.

Comment: @RomainValeri sounds good, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @matt that could hardly count as a good naming convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Git sort refnames

The Git commands that sort refnames each have their own custom sorting code.  (This is a bit unfortunate as it means the sorting options are inconsistent in some Git releases.)  At some point in the not-very-distant past, `git branch` and `git tag` were reworked to share at least *some* code with `git for-each-ref` so that they now *are* consistent, but they still have some separate code.

> and where do I read up on that?

Each command has its own documentation: [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), and so on.

The `git branch` command in particular is what Git calls *porcelain:* a command aimed at use by humans.  Porcelain commands often take configuration directives from [the files manipulated by `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), and `git branch` is among these: you can set `branch.sort` to affect how it sorts branches.

(This option is not available in some ancient versions of Git.)

Comment: thank you that bit of history of git, I have assumed there would be one sorting mechanism for all.

something strange: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref opens an empty page for some reason... I've checked, it's the same link as in the git docs and that one opens empty page too.

Comment: well, that was a glitch, git-for-each-ref opens the correct page now

Comment: So let me check if I understood this right.

Docs for branch says: "Sort order defaults <..> to sorting based on the full refname".
Docs for git-for-each-ref says: "For sorting purposes, fields with numeric values sort in numeric order <..> All other fields are used to sort in their byte-value order."

If I don't specify any sorting anywhere and just call `git branch`, it will show first local branches, then remote branches, both sorted by comparing byte values of their names, right?

Comment: Right.  Hence @matt suggestion of a name composed of `z`s, which have the highest possible byte value while still being alphanumeric.